# A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'EnvironmentName' VSTS Build Definition

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, powershell-remoting, azure-pipelines, build-definition

I was trying to do a Build Definition in VSTS and i was getting the following error:

> A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name
>   'EnvironmentName'
>   Task PowerShellOnTargetMachines failed. This caused the job to fail. Look at the logs for the task for more details.

I wasnt capable of doing a Build Definition:

- Copy Files to a Windows Machine
- Run a powerShell Script

I Configure virtual machines with powershell remote scripting.

[image: Here it is the Build ScreenShot]

[image: Here it is my PowerShell Script Build Configuration]

Comment: Can you check whether the username password and ip:port of the machine is correct. This error comes up when one of the info is wrong.

Comment: I just checked the information.
Credentials (Username, Password) are correct
I have a Virtual Machine Running in Azure
I wrote Public IP: Port 

Still getting the same error.

Comment: Aditionally,
I think is a VSTS Bug. I Just Checked some post in GitHub:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/issues/849 
https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/issues/867

Comment: This is either a bug with VSTS or Azure's new resource management deployment model, this was working for me 2 weeks ago but since the switched to the new ARM model nothing works for continous integration. Now I'm stuck with the azure blob copy, then rdp into the VM and running the powershell scripts manually....I really hope this is fixed soon or a tutorial is made

Comment: Microsoft Documentation is limited.
they should make a kind of tutorial videos of each of the functionalities offered by VSTS as well as the orderly and clear documentation of the requirements for each of its functions.

Comment: @DiegoCastilloCastillo Thanks for the feedback. We are aware of this issue and are currently working on simplifying the task and making docs more comprehensive.
Note - I work in VSTS team at Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks to you for the comment.
I'll be looking forward to the new features in VSTS.